# HTML5 Local Storage input not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm struggling to see what is wrong with my code.  I've coded a local storage app to show user inputs, however, what is being input, is not displaying on the screen.

I'll show my code and hopefully someone can see an error somewhere, I think it should be working fine?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Premier League Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="elliot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
    <h1>Premier League Site</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id ="Menu_Bar">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Teams</li>
        <li>Extras</li>
    </ul>

    </nav>

    <section id="sectionone">
        <form>
            <p>(key) One: <input type="text" id="one"></p>
            <p>(value) Two <textarea id="two"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="button" id="button" value="Save"></p>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="sectiontwo">
        Stored Info should go here
    </section>  
    <footer id="footer">
        Elliot Harrison 2014
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is my HTML code, here is my Javascript code.

```
    function doFirst(){
    var button = document.getElementbyId("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", saveStuff, false);
}

function saveStuff(){
    var one = document.getElementbyId("one").value;
    var two = document.getElementbyId("two").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem(one,two);

    display(one);
}

function display(one){
    var sectiontwo = document.getElementbyId("sectiontwo");
    var two = sessionStorage.getItem(one);
    sectiontwo.innerHTML = "Name of variable: "+one+"<br />Value: "+two;
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Can anyone notice anything wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Noticed one problem, I did not have ">" at the end of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, you have to use `getElementById` instead of `getElementbyId`.

there is also antoher error in your html:

```
<p>(key) One: <input type="text" id="one" /></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, such a simple error.  Yet, I've been looking for over an hour!